# How to force a java app to use a local version of a maven dependency?

Tags: java, maven

I have two separate projects: a java library and a java web app that uses the library as dependency. Both use maven.

In some cases I do changes on both at the same time, and I'd like to configure the java app to use my local version of the library, instead of fetching from maven repository.

My current workflow is the current:

1. Do the changed on the library
2. Compile and deploy the library to the local maven repository (`mvn clean install`)
3. On the java app, set it offline and run a `mvn clean install` to update the dependency.

This sounds cumbersome, can someone suggest a smarter approach?

thanks

Comment: Maven has a "system" scope which purely uses a path on the local filesystem and doesn't lookup the artifact in any repo https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#system-dependencies

Comment: Best would be to create a multi module build where one module is the "lib" and the other module is the app which uses that...examples like  https://github.com/khmarbaise/javaee

Comment: You should not have a modified local copy of an artifact.  Create a new one with another version number instead and revise your project to use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is local version. But I guess you need something more than this. Give more details if you need.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.group.project</groupId>
<artifactId>Project</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<scope>system</scope>
<systemPath>${basedir}/lib/project-1.0.0.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```